# android widget after onDelete still listening

Tags: android, widget, listener

I have a Service that calls some update-methods in a `GameLogic`-singleton. The`GameLogic` may decide that some status-update is needed. In this case it informs its listeners about a `StatusUpdateEvent`. The listeneres then update their view etc.

```
public class GameLogic {
    // ... attributes ...
    private static GameLogic instance = null;
    private GameLogic() {
        // singleton pattern
    }
    public static synchronized GameLogic getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new GameLogic();
        }
        return instance;
    }
    public void checkStatus() {
        // called by service
        // ... some checks
        notifyStatusUpdate(new StatusUpdateEvent());
    }
    public void addStatusUpdateListener(StatusUpdateListener listener) {
        if (!listeners.contains(listener)) {
            listeners.add(listener);
        }
    }
    public void removeStatusUpdateListener(StatusUpdateListener listener) {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }
    protected synchronized void notifyStatusUpdate(StatusUpdateEvent event) {
        for (StatusUpdateListener l : listeners) {
            l.onStatusUpdate(event);
        }
    }
}
```

I have a widget that should listen to the `StatusUpdateEvent`:

```
public class ProjectWidget extends AppWidgetProvider implements StatusUpdateListener {
    // ... attributes ...
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        this.context = context;
        this.appWidgetManager = appWidgetManager;
        this.remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_2x1);
        this.thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, ProjectWidget.class);

        GameLogic.getInstance().addStatusUpdateListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "onDeleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        GameLogic.getInstance().removeStatusUpdateListener(this);
        super.onDeleted(context, appWidgetIds);
    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusUpdate(StatusUpdateEvent e) {
        android.util.Log.d("ProjectWidget", "onStatusUpdate");
        // here some class fields are updated like this.project = e.getProject();
        // ...
        updateViews();
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
    }
    // ... updateViews() etc.
}
```

But the problem now is:
I add the widget to the homescreen, everythings fine. Then if I delete the widget from the homescreen, I see the onDelete Toast, but afterwards I still see that Log entry: ProjectWidget onStatusUpdate.

So the listener is not removed.. why? and how can I do that stuff?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So the listener is not removed.. why? and how can I do that stuff?

What you have is a memory leak.

The `AppWidgetProvider` is a transient object. It will live long enough to process an `onUpdate()` or other app widget lifecycle method, and then it goes away.

Never never never never *never* ***never*** try to have an `AppWidgetProvider` live longer than this, such as by registering it in a static context as you are. You are leaking memory, as the `AppWidgetProvider` will not get garbage-collected.

When you are calling `removeStatusUpdateListener()`, you have a different `AppWidgetProvider` instance than you used with `addStatusUpdateListener()`. Hence, the remove operation is a no-op (you are removing something never registered), and the original listener will remain there forever.

Have your `GameLogic` or whatever update your app widget `RemoteViews` directly.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of the transiency of the AppWidgetProvider! I'm now doing it from the service:

 Context context = this;
 AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
 RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_2x1);
 ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, MyWidget.class);
 remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.my_text_view, "myText" + System.currentTimeMillis());
 appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);

Comment: @Stuck: Yup, that's a fine approach. `AppWidgetProvider` really is only an event handler for lifecycle events -- you can update the app widget `RemoteViews` from anywhere.